# Hadoop commands from python

Tags: python, shell, hadoop

I am trying to get some stats for a directory in hdfs. I am trying to get the no of files/subdirs and the size for each. I started out thinking that I can do this in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
OP=$(hadoop fs -ls hdfs://mydirectory)
echo $(wc -l < "$OP")
```

I only have this much so far and I quickly realised that python might be a better option for this. However I am not able to figure out how to execute hadoop commands like `hadoop fs -ls from python`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html for your options, including how to get the return status (in case of an error).  The basic code you're missing is

```
import commands

hdir_list = commands.getoutput('hadoop fs -ls hdfs://mydirectory')
```

---

Yes: deprecated in 2.6, still useful in 2.7, but removed from Python 3.  If that bothers you, switch to

```
os.command (<code string>)
```

... or better yet use **subprocess.call** (introduced in 2.4).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-ls", "/user"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in output.stdout:
    print(line)
```

Additionally, you can refer to [this sub-process example](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/92321/interacting-with-hadoop-hdfs-using-python-codes.html), where you can get return status, output and error message separately.